# iPhone 5 can't open webpages when VPN is on

Tags: ios, vpn, web-browsing

I'm using iPhone 5 and iPad 2, not jailbroken, with iOS 6.1.4 and VPN turned on. Safari and any other browser apps can't open pages.

Comment: It appears your question got cut off. What do you see? Do any websites work?

Comment: Maybe you might need to use a proxy ?